# Can I run something like "git difftool -d" where one of the sides is the live working copy?

Tags: git

I understand how this command works:

```
git difftool -d A B
```

It "checks out" a snapshot of all the files in A and B that *differ* into two temporary folders, complete with the necessary directory structure, then it pops the difftool on those two directories.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way for git to do the following:

```
git difftool -d A <live working copy>
```

I understand that the live working copy will contain all the files of the repository and not just those that differ.

The motivation behind this question is that the difftool I use, [Beyond Compare 4](https://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php) lets me edit the files and save the changes. It allows me to compare a file (the left and the right "side") and bring changes from one side to the other, and even do manual corrections.

This would be nice to say "Let me compare against what it was before I started changing, because I need to undo a couple of changes".

Most IDEs that have git integration allows this kind of partial undo, and `git diff` allows me to use the command line to bring back chunks (if I remember correctly).

So can this be done with careful construction of git parameters?

This is on Windows 10 with latest version of both git and Beyond Compare if any of that matters.

Note that if git alone cannot be coaxed to do this the question can morph into this: Can I ask git to copy a snapshot of all the files that differ between a particular commit and the live index into a folder structure? If so then I can easily create a git-partial-undo bash script that does this myself.

For instance, if I could easily get git to extract the following files into a temporary folder:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB HEAD~2

src/a/b.txt
src/b/other.txt
```

Then I could easily just pop the comparison tool between that folder and the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post an answer but it's a horrible answer in my opinion, there's probably way too much code, I'm on the opposite end of the scale of "good at bash programming", etc.

What I ended up doing is the following:

1. I work out which commit to compare against (the other side of the comparison will always be the local working folder)
2. I ask git to produce a list of differences between that commit and the local folder

   - Note that I skipped the `A` type of modification using the filter because in that case the path to the file will refer to the local folder and not that other commit
   - Corollary; that may be true for some of the other modification types as well, I'll fix that if I encounter it
3. I then run through each modified file and grab a copy of it from that commit into a temporary file in a fresh temporary folder, complete with directory structure
4. Lastly I pop Beyond Compare on top of that temporary folder and the local folder

   - I need to explicitly ask Beyond Compare to only compare files and not show orphans on the right side, otherwise the local folder will be full of files. I realize some modifications to the files like additions and deletions will not make sense with this setup but that's just how it is.

As such, here's the code, read it and weep:

```
#!/bin/sh

if ! git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo error: not in a git repository or work tree
    exit 1
fi;

COMMIT=$(git rev-parse $1)
COMMIT_NAME="Commit $1"
if [ "$COMMIT" != "$1" ]; then
    COMMIT_NAME="$COMMIT_NAME = $COMMIT"
fi
if [ -z "$COMMIT" ]; then
    if [ -z "$(git status -s)" ]; then
        echo "No changes"
        exit 0
    else
        echo "Comparing against unmodified"
        COMMIT_NAME="Unmodified"
        COMMIT=HEAD
    fi
fi

TEMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
CHANGES=$(git diff --name-status --diff-filter=DCMRTUXB $COMMIT)
ANY_CHANGES=0
while read -r LINE;
do
    MODIFICATION=${LINE:0:1}
    if [ -z "$MODIFICATION" ]; then
        continue
    fi
    FILENAME=${LINE:2}
    TARGET=$TEMPDIR/$FILENAME
    TARGET_DIR=$(dirname "${TARGET}")
    mkdir -p $TARGET_DIR
    git show "$COMMIT:$FILENAME" > $TARGET
    ANY_CHANGES=1
done <<< $CHANGES

if [ "$ANY_CHANGES" = "1" ]; then
    BC=$(echo "/$DROPBOX/Tools/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe" | sed 's/\\/\//g' | sed 's/://')
    "$BC" $TEMPDIR . //leftreadonly //title1="$COMMIT_NAME"
else
    echo "No changes detected"
fi
rm -rf "$TEMPDIR"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used Beyond Compare in the following way to get the result I think you're after.

For example, say that I have a git branch I'm currently working in that I would like to compare to what's in the master branch...

1. First, I make sure my branch is up to date with any other merges to master by doing a `git merge master` to pick up those changes.
2. I do a `git difftool -d master`.  This creates two separate temp directories with the master on the left and my branch on the right.  (Having already set up BC.exe as my difftool via `git config...` at some earlier point)
3. I can see the paths to those temp folders in BC, so I go there and zip up the contents.  (If I don't do that, but try to just point the right-hand path in BC to the working directory of my branch, the left-hand folder disappears, as I imagine it thinks the diff process has finished and it cleans up).
4. I move that zip to whereever is convenient and I can then use BC to just diff the left folder (conveniently named 'left', at least for me), with my branch's working directory.

Since you did a `git merge master` earlier, you can just use the "Diffs No Orphans" button in BC's folder view to see only the changes you made.